# Reinstall Apache with Apache Handler over FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

We are currently running apache with fastcgi. Here is what it says on our `phpinfo`:

`Server API     CGI/FastCGI`

We need to change that to be Apache.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is hardcoded. It is set on startup by the specific handler (FCGI, mod_php, ...).

If this is really essential you might need to change the php sourcecode and compile it.

(See `sapi/cgi/cgi_main.c:946`)